# How to fix segmentation fault for while loop in c

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm working on an assignment and trying to write the code to answer this question:

> Write a program that computes the total weight of a cargo. The user has many types of boxes (numbered 1 to n). For each box type, the program asks the user about the weight and quantity. The program thencomputes and prints the total cargo weight.
>   In the output sample below, the user has three box types. For box type 2, the user enters the sentinel -1 to
>   indicate they’re done with the input. Your program should print Type 1, 2, 3, etc. as shown in the
>   output below.

```
Enter weight (lbs) of Type 1 box: 4
Enter quantity: 2
Enter weight (lbs) of Type 2 box: -1 
The total weight is 8 lbs.
```

When i run this code it runs the first line to input weight but then gives me a segmentation fault and says (core dumped). -1 is the sentinel and even when the enter weight is inside the while loop the result is the same. What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry I'm new to C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int weight; //weight of boxes
    int quantity; //number of boxes 
    int total_weight; //total weight
    int n = 1;

    printf("Enter weight (lbs) of Type %d box: ", n);
    scanf("%d", weight);
    while(weight!=-1) //Iterate loop until w=-1 
    {
        printf("Enter quantity: \n");
        scanf("%d", quantity);

        total_weight= total_weight + (quantity*weight);
        n++;
    }

    printf("The total weight is %0.2d", total_weight);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Fix them all.

Comment: `scanf("%d", weight);` ==> `scanf("%d", &weight);` and same for `quantity`.

Comment: And do **check** the return value of `scanf()`

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you use `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", weight);
scanf("%d", quantity);
```

You should pass the address of the variable, not the value of the variable.

That would look like this:

```
scanf("%d", &weight);
scanf("%d", &quantity);
```

---

Your while loop depends on value `weight`.  The value of `weight` never changes in your loop, so the loop can never exit.

---

This line:

```
total_weight= total_weight + (quantity*weight);
```

uses the value of `total_weight`, which was never initialized.
You should initialize your variables.

---

All in all, I think your fixed code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int weight       = 0; //weight of boxes
    int quantity     = 0; //number of boxes 
    int total_weight = 0; //total weight
    int n            = 1;

    while(weight!=-1)
    {
        printf("Enter weight (lbs) of Type %d box: ", n);
        scanf("%d", &weight);        // Update weight **inside** the loop
        printf("Enter quantity: \n");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);

        total_weight= total_weight + (quantity*weight);
        n++;
    }

    printf("The total weight is %0.2d", total_weight);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even after my fixes to the code, I spotted one more bug that remains.   But this should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(weight!=-1) //Iterate loop until w=-1 
{
printf("Enter quantity: \n");
scanf("%d", quantity);

total_weight= total_weight + (quantity*weight);
n++;
}
```

Problem is in while condition, weight never change it's value so the condition always true  so infinite loop.

Fix this statement `scanf("%d", &weight);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to assign a value to the pointer of `quantity` and `weight`, instead you need to put `&quantity` and `&weight` also you do not have another input for the weight, you should also use a do while instead of a while loop. It should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int weight; //weight of boxes
int quantity; //number of boxes 
int total_weight; //total weight
int n = 1;
    do
    {
    printf("Enter weight (lbs) of Type %d box: ", n);
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    printf("Enter quantity: \n");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);

    total_weight= total_weight + (quantity*weight);
    n++;
}while (weight != -1);

printf("The total weight is %0.2d", total_weight);
return 0;
```

}